# Isolate graphic components in Manipulate

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I have cobbled together two Wolfram Demonstration files to produce the code below. My objective is to generate the phase plane plot on the left side of the output by clicking in one of the regions of the trace-determinant plot on the right side of the output. I generate the 2d linear system of differential equations from the matrix

$m=( {
  {2 h + 1, -1},
  {(1 + h)^2 - k, -1}
 } )$,   where 
    $h$ = 0.5 trA; $k$.  = 0.25 (trA^2 - 4 detA).

I have to create the linear transformation

trA = 4.84 p[[1]] - 12.58; detA = 5.49 p[[2]] + 2.36

from the trace-determinate plane to calculate the correct values of $h$ and $k$. Prior to introducing the StreamPlot, the Locator in the trace-determinant plane provided the correct values of trA and detA. After my introduction of StreamPlot, the coordinates of the Locator appeared to be based on the entire graphic output. Not knowing how to isolate the StreamPlot output from the trace-determinant output, I devised the transformation kludge above.

I also want to be able to move the Locator more precisely, especially in the neighborhood of any of the defining plots (p1, p2, ...,p6). Perhaps sliders could help so I can increment their values to what ever precision I define. But because of my transformation kludge, I am not able to accomplish this. Nevertheless, I want to keep the Locator and just add sliders (1d or 2d).

Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[
 m = {{2 h + 1, -1}, {(1 + h)^2 - k, -1}};
 {eigvals, eigvecs} = Eigensystem[m];

p1 = Show[Plot[1/4 x^2, {x, -400, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thickness[0.01]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4.5, 9}}, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["tr \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"A\",\nFontFamily->\"Courier New\"]\)", 18], 
   Style["det A", 18]}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400},
  Filling -> Top, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Hue[0.3]]]];

 p2 = Plot[1/4 x^2, {x, 0, 400}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4.5, 9}}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Filling -> Top, 
FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Hue[0.1]]];

 p3 = Plot[1/4 x^2, {x, 0, 400}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, Axes -> None, 
PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4.5, 9}}, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Filling -> Axis, 
FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Hue[0.5]]];

 p4 = Plot[1/4 x^2, {x, -400, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thick},
 Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4.5, 9}}, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Filling -> Axis, 
FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Hue[0.7]]];

 p5 = Plot[0, {x, -400, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.001]}, 
Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4.5, 9}}, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Filling -> Bottom, 
FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Hue[0.9]]];

p6 = Plot[0, {x, 0, 400}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.001]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4.5, 9}}, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Axes -> None, 
Filling -> Bottom, 
FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.15], Hue[0.9]]];

 trA = 4.84 p[[1]] - 12.58; detA = 5.49 p[[2]] + 2.36;
 h = 0.5 trA; k = 0.25 (trA^2 - 4 detA);

 Grid[{{Show[
 StreamPlot[m.{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic}, 
  StreamPoints -> 
   ControlActive[.5 {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, Coarse],
   StreamStyle -> Thickness[Medium], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   StreamScale -> Large, Frame -> False, Ticks -> None], 
 If[eigvecs == Re[eigvecs], 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[t eigvecs], {t, -3, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}}], {}], PlotRange -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> {350, 350}],
 Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, Graphics[
  {Thickness[0.01], Brown, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}}], 
   Thickness[0.01], Green, Line[{{-6, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
   Thickness[0.01], Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 9}}], 
   Thickness[0.01], Purple, Dashed, Line[{{0, -4.5}, {0, 0}}]}],
 ImageSize -> {400, 400}, FrameTicks -> None] } 
   }],

 Row[{Spacer[280], Text@Style["Eigenvalues:  "],
   Dynamic[{
 NumberForm[h - Sqrt[k], 3],
 NumberForm[h + Sqrt[k], 3]}]}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 17}],

{{p, {2.577, -0.75}}, {1.36, -1.25}, {3.84, 1.21}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}]},
ImageSize -> 12]}]
```

I hope that my code is suitably formatted for MMA SE. If not, please advise me how to modify it.

Comment: To move the locator more precisely, hold down the option key while you are dragging the locator around.

Comment: @bill s: Your suggestion for more precise Locator control is useful but does not go to the heart of my query. In order to position the Locator as close as I can to land on the parabola [4*detA = (trA)^2 ], it would be desirable to use some kind of slider whose values I can specify (up to a predefined tolerance). I don't know how to incorporate a slider what works in conjunction with the Locator.